# Complex(?) filtering in Excel, select only 'highest' rated from list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm sure this is straightforward but I can't work it out.

I have a long list of applications with a categorisation of 0 - 2.

```
app_id  app_sc          CAT
1001    Application 1   CAT 0
1001    Application 1   CAT 1
1002    Application 2   CAT 2
1003    Application 3   CAT 0
1004    Application 4   CAT 0
1005    Application 5   CAT 0
1005    Application 5   CAT 1
1005    Application 5   CAT 2
1006    Application 6   CAT 1
1006    Application 6   CAT 2
1007    Application 7   CAT 1
1007    Application 7   CAT 2
1008    Application 8   CAT 1
1009    Application 9   CAT 2
```

I want to create a new list filtered to select only the item that has the lowest CAT value, where there are duplicate application names it should discard those with a higher CAT value.

The table above would result in:

```
1001    Application 1   CAT 0
1002    Application 2   CAT 2
1003    Application 3   CAT 0
1004    Application 4   CAT 0
1005    Application 5   CAT 0
1006    Application 6   CAT 1
1007    Application 7   CAT 1
1008    Application 8   CAT 1
1009    Application 9   CAT 2
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of formulas you tried that didn't work?

Comment: No because I don't really understand where to start, I'd be happy to go away and find out for myself but I'm not even sure what I'm looking for. Can this be achieved through formula? PowerQuery? I understand people don't appreciate it when someone posts showing zero effort but I honestly have made no headway. I could do it in minutes in powershell but that isn't an option here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I understood, from your OP, you could use one of the following approaches to accomplish the desired output:

[image]

---

• Using Excel Formulas --> Applicable to `MS365` Beta Channel Users.

```
=LET(α, GROUPBY(A2:B15,TEXTAFTER(C2:C15," ")/1,MIN,0,0), HSTACK(TAKE(α,,2),"Cat "&DROP(α,,2)))
```

---

• Using `POWER QUERY` which is available from `Excel 2010+` onwards Windows and MAC.

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"app_id", "app_sc"}, {{"ALL", each List.Min([CAT]), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

[image]

---

Comment: Thank you, the advanced grouping in powerquery worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Sort on CAT, pick you desired candidate(s), re-sort on app_id to restore original order if necessary. You can do a similar thing to delete duplicate applicants.

- Highlight all the columns.
- Select "Data" from the tabs at the top and click on the "Filter" icon.
- Each column title (row 1) now has a drop down menu enabling you to sort and/or select it's content and all the   other columns will keep in step.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't say in my OP but I was really looking for a programmatic method to do this as my source data is actually a list of 47 thousand items.